# WordPress Admin Page

Tags: admin

... I moved the account link to the trash bin, and I'm not able to access it, I've login, but I am not able to make changes or able to logout, how can I restore the Admin page, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your Admin page should be available at: yourwebsite.com/wp-admin/ or yourwebsite.com/wp-login.php. 
Have you tried to enter the URL manually?